# How to disable IP tracking in Android Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

For GDPR purposes I would need to turn off or mask the ip address tracking in Firebase analytics.
I found the option to disable ip tracking in Fabric console, but nothing related to Firebase. Also it seems that there is no API available into the Android SDK.
Anybody with same issue?